# Git reset seems to create branch, not remove commits

Tags: git, reset

Im using `git reset --hard <commit>` to try to move my repo code back to the previous commit, so deleting 1 commit but after I execute the statement, there seems to be a local branch created and the commits between current head and previous commit still exist.

I read that the commits are orphaned until garbage collection is complete, so tried to force GC but it did not help. I expected the head to move to previous commit but it did not happen.

Any help or direction to docs that would make this clearer for me would be appreciated

Comment: What does `git status` and `git log` show? Didn't it move backwards in the commit history?

Comment: You can try cloning the commit you want into another folder to test it. And if all else fails you can manually make changes based on the number of the commit changes.

Comment: Which tool do you use to view your repository? Sounds like you have a remote branch that stays on the previous commit.

Comment: Yes actually when i look in git log i no longer see that commit. I am using SourceTree to view the repo.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git reset`, if you have a branch checked out, then that branch will move to the target commit.  Any other branches (or any other refs) will remain unchanged (and the old commits will remain in the overall history).  If you are in detached HEAD state when you run `git reset`, then no branch is checked out and so no branch will move.

By default git only shows reachable commits.  I'm not sure what command is showing you that the commits still exist, but in most cases, the fact that they are shown would mean that a ref is still pointing to them - which is one reason `gc` would not help.

There are a few types of ref that could be keeping the commits "alive".

Even if the local branch moved (and was the only branch), there might be a corresponding remote tracking ref - there would be if the branch is shared in a remote.  That raises additional concerns, though (see below).  There also could be tags, or a few other more obscure things.

Since the most likely issue is a remote tracking ref, it's important to understand that removing commits from a ref's history is called a "history rewrite", and that doing a history rewrite of a shared branch has costs.  This is described in the `git rebase` documentation under "recovering from upstream rebase".  (While it is documented as having to do with rebase, it actually applies to all rewrites.)

If there is a remote tracking branch that needs to be moved, and if you decide to go ahead with the history rewrite in spite of the costs of doing so, then you would do a forced push to update the remote branch (and the remote tracking ref).

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

It is important that the history rewrite is communicated/coordinated with all other repo users; if they do the wrong thing in trying to recover, it could undo the history rewrite.

Once all refs are moved, most commands will not show the "removed" commits, but they still physically exist.  In fact, they still won't be immediately eligible for `gc` because your local repo has a set of "reflogs" that keep track of the history of every branch as well as the symbolic ref `HEAD`.  So if you've had the commits checked out, or if any branch has included them, then the corresponding reflogs can be used to recover them even after the branch and other refs have moved.  Which means the commits can't yet be physically deleted.

You can cause the reflogs to expire (or delete the reflog files themselves); see the `git reflog` docs.  Or you can wait for the reflogs to expire on their own.  After that, the commits will be deleted.

However, depending how the remote is hosted, a separate procedure might be needed to remove the commits from its copy of the database.  And there is absolutely nothing you can do to force other users to physically discard those commits from their clones.  So if deleting the information from the repo is important, then you'll need the cooperation of everyone with a clone; and if the reasons for deleting the commits include that they contain sensitive information, then you need to consider that information compromised (such as by changing any passwords that were exposed in this way, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

My apologies all i just realised that my commits were actually pushed to the origin so i wasn't following the correct workflow. I have tested the reset "locally" and the commits are deleted as expected, thanks for getting back to me.